# Parsing a String for Special characters in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am getting a string in the following format in the query string:

```
Arnstung%20Chew(20)
```

I want to convert it to just `Arnstung Chew`.

How do I do it?

Also how do I make sure that the user is not passing a script or anything harmful in the query string?

Comment: Define a non special character

Comment: do you want to remove everything that is wrapped in brackets or all non text characters?

Comment: That should actually be "Arnstung%20Chew%20(20)", how is the string being passed to the querystring?

Comment: Yes thanks I changd my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string str = "Arnstung Chew (20)";

string replacedString = str.Substring(0, str.IndexOf("(") -1 ).Trim();

string safeString = System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(replacedString);
```

Comment: just a small change..what if the string is like "Arnstung%20Chew (20)"

Comment: Then I would use `string replacedString = str.Substring(0, str.IndexOf("("));`

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to provide a comprehensive answer without knowing what variations might appear on your input text. For example, will there always be two words separated by a space followed by a number in parentheses? Or might there be other variations as well?

I have a lot of parsing code on my [Black Belt Coder](http://www.blackbeltcoder.com) site, including a [sscanf() replacement for .NET](http://www.blackbeltcoder.com/Articles/strings/a-sscanf-replacement-for-net) that may potentially be useful in your case.